# Unable to print data from a large array in C?

Tags: arrays

I am working in Visual express 2010, in my practice project i have an array of six col and around 1350 rows. The idea is to check numbers repeatedly appeared in array and print full row.
          When i try to read and print it, i think it is only checking for first five rows. It wont identify the number appearing past this five rows. Please help me i have added a code here with less number of rows for verification.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


unsigned const int arr[][6];

void main()
{
    unsigned int flag = 0;

    unsigned int i,j,col=5,row=5,input,k;
    printf("\nPlease enter the number to be checked: \n");
    scanf("%d",&input);



    for(i=0;i<=row;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<=col;j++)
    {
        if(input==arr[i][j])
        {
            flag = 1;
            for(k=0;k<=col;k++)
            printf("%d \t",arr[i][k]);
            printf("\n");
            //break;
        }
    }//if(flag==1)
        //break;
    }

    if(flag==0)
            printf("oops...\n");
    else
        flag=0;




        getch();
}


unsigned int arr[][6]={ 
                        9,  16, 22, 33, 4,  37, 
                        4,  12, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
                        7,  15, 19, 21, 25, 41, 
                        8,  18, 19, 25, 26, 29, 
                        5,  7,  10, 26, 29, 32, 
                        2,  4,  7,  19, 25, 27, 
                        2,  10, 14, 22, 23, 34, 
                        1,  8,  16, 31, 40, 43,
                        3,  8,  15, 16, 23, 25,
                        5,  24, 31, 36, 40, 44,
                        3,  9,  20, 29, 36, 44,
                        18, 21, 24, 25, 26, 44,
                        2,  8,  12, 15, 22, 35,
                        4,  9,  28, 32, 35, 39,
                        18, 19, 20, 29, 32, 40,
                        14, 16, 29, 41, 42, 43,
                        2,  6,  27, 35, 41, 44,
                        7,  9,  11, 20, 28, 36,
                        10, 16, 22, 23, 27, 37,
                        8,  10, 14, 29, 35, 38,
                        2,  10, 18, 27, 28, 36,
                        2,  11, 17, 29, 32, 40,
                        4,  7,  17, 23, 33, 37,
                        7,  26, 29, 31, 33, 38,
                        2,  8,  18, 33, 35, 41,
                        1,  5,  14, 36, 41, 44,
                        9,  12, 17, 24, 30, 44,
                        8,  12, 16, 33, 38, 40,
                        4,  6,  12, 13, 25, 32,
                        7,  15, 31, 32, 38, 43,
                        9,  14, 15, 18, 19, 25,
                        7,  11, 21, 32, 40, 45,
                        2,  3,  29, 30, 35, 43,
                        1,  4,  14, 16, 30, 45,
                        18, 19, 20, 28, 33, 36,
                        1,  12, 18, 20, 26, 42,
                        1,  6,  8,  30, 32, 41,
                        1,  2,  12, 15, 38, 39,
                        11, 23, 31, 33, 40, 42,
                        3,  8,  13, 17, 31, 39,
                        23, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39,
                        1,  6,  8,  27, 33, 39,
                        7,  22, 23, 35, 37, 45,
                        12, 14, 24, 32, 37, 40,
                        4,  6,  7,  25, 29, 42,
                        2,  11, 15, 19, 27, 31,
                        6,  11, 20, 31, 35, 44,
                        3,  12, 26, 33, 41, 44,
                        7,  9,  14, 20, 35, 41,
                        13, 16, 19, 40, 41, 44,
                        17, 23, 25, 36, 39, 43,
                        7,  10, 11, 16, 32, 33,
                        4,  16, 17, 27, 41, 42,
                        12, 13, 18, 34, 40, 45,
                        26, 29, 38, 41, 43, 44,
                        9,  12, 24, 25, 26, 43,
                        1,  2,  16, 24, 32, 38,
                        23, 26, 27, 36, 38, 44,
                        19, 21, 25, 27, 42, 45,
                        5,  10, 21, 22, 25, 27,
                        8,  19, 21, 31, 33, 42,
                        5,  7,  8,  13, 39, 45,
                        2,  10, 11, 14, 43, 44,
                        3,  8,  9,  24, 31, 39,
                        2,  3,  17, 26, 29, 44,
                        10, 14, 27, 28, 41, 43,
                        9,  21, 25, 27, 34, 37,
                        10, 17, 25, 27, 41, 42,
                        11, 12, 15, 25, 34, 35,
                        13, 26, 38, 41, 43, 44,
                        17, 20, 25, 30, 32, 40,
                        1,  2,  8,  12, 16, 20,
                        1,  12, 13, 34, 36, 39,
                        29, 32, 34, 37, 41, 42,
                        19, 20, 23, 31, 35, 36,
                        4,  6,  8,  12, 17, 18,
                        4,  11, 12, 18, 19, 23,
                        6,  8,  14, 15, 19, 44,
                        3,  11, 14, 22, 32, 40,
                        13, 21, 25, 31, 41, 42,
                        7,  10, 16, 17, 26, 28,
                        6,  7,  8,  11, 21, 29,
                        3,  8,  27, 33, 34, 38,
                        5,  11, 15, 18, 36, 42,
                        4,  10, 15, 19, 24, 34,
                        3,  6,  12, 28, 41, 42,
                        3,  8,  26, 27, 36, 42,
                        5,  9,  15, 24, 30, 44,
                        2,  5,  22, 25, 37, 43,
                        3,  10, 16, 26, 28, 31,
                        8,  9,  21, 23, 35, 44,
                        7,  10, 16, 20, 22, 42,
                        2,  6,  8,  11, 37, 40,
                        6,  14, 16, 26, 33, 45,
                        2,  5,  6,  20, 22, 40,
                        2,  3,  7,  15, 16, 26,
                        5,  6,  7,  22, 26, 34,
                        3,  18, 31, 36, 39, 44,
                        9,  22, 25, 26, 31, 35,
                        1,  18, 20, 37, 42, 43,
                        2,  3,  5,  24, 25, 42,
                        6,  15, 22, 33, 35, 45,
                        4,  18, 21, 30, 32, 33,
                        20, 27, 33, 34, 38, 41,
                        15, 20, 22, 25, 40, 43,
                        3,  22, 26, 31, 36, 40,
                        26, 33, 35, 40, 41, 45,
                        21, 26, 32, 36, 42, 43,
                        5,  13, 21, 31, 38, 45,
                        3,  9,  20, 28, 29, 32,
                        10, 20, 21, 23, 25, 38,
                        11, 13, 16, 19, 24, 43,
                        1,  5,  9,  18, 33, 34,

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the row variable size to your total number of rows in that array, instead of 5 then the loop can scan your total array and then it'll print your answer.

I hope you'll get this.

Regards
[c-codeWorld](http://www.ccodeworld.blogspot.com)